# Crack LCG given 2 output values only

Tags: randomness

I want to try to break an LCG generator just as programming practice task. I found similar issue at [Cracking a linear congruential generator](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4268/cracking-a-linear-congruential-generator).

Assume that *m* is given. The answer to the link above assumes that there are 3 consecutive output values given. Then it is just solving the resulting 2 linear equations. But what if there are only 2 values given? For some values, there probably will be several candidate LCG. How to list all of them and do so efficiently?

Comment: Actually there are three unknowns in \begin{align}s_{n+1}&=a\cdot s_n+b\bmod m\\s_{n+2}&=a\cdot s_{n+1}+b\bmod m\end{align}, namely $s_n,a,b$ and so you need three equations to properly determine all three.

Comment: And that's why there are many possible solutions. This is practical programming task from my algorithms course and I know people who've solved it, so I'm sure there is some way...